# Facebook - Website Integration

Tags: php, facebook

I'm integrating facebook for a website that has the ff. flow:

1. Website has no connect with facebook button on login and sign-up page
2. After sign-up, user will be ask if he/she wants to connect facebook account with just basic information and email as permissions
3. If user allowed integration, the facebook user id will be saved.
4. Facebook user id will be used in FQL

**My problem is, with no facebook connect on login and sign-up pages**

When I try to do multi-friend selector, if the user currently logged in has not logged in at 'facebook.com', 
I'm receiving Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session thrown

**Which means in order for some facebook integration to work such as inviting friends, user have to be logged in facebook as well.**

**Is there a way to login both website and facebook.com with just facebook user id saved in the database? Something like, "if I detected this user id, autologin to facebook" in able to create session**

P.S I've done facebook integration before and I have no problem because it has facebook connect in login and sign-up page which creates the session needed if the user chooses to login via that button.

Your help will be very much appreciated. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

When a user authenticates with your site/access your app you can get a user access token that can be used in your subsequent API calls.  It expires when they change their password or revoke/remove your app.

Check out this link for details related to authenticate, the user access token and the callbacks so you can maintain an up to date database: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/